# What profiler could I use to generate a "timeline" for my c++ openMP program?

Tags: c++, profiler

I want to profile my openMP program and I think a timeline for all threads would be good, I have tried several tools, however.

1. valgrind doesn't give timeline, it just gives the callmap
2. vtune is not free, and I really can't afford it.
3. I need to be a root to install Zoom.
4. To use scalasca, I have to install score-P, however, there are some errors about the Qt.

So, is there any good profiler that is free, could generate timeline and could be installed by a non-root user?

Comment: What information is it that you're trying to gather?  Execution times?  Time spent in functions?

Comment: This site doesn't accept questions asking for recommendations (see the [help/on-topic]). [softwarerecs.se] is in beta, and may accept it, but be sure and read their guidelines first; they're rather strict.

Comment: I had read somewhere that linux bundles a profiler with itself , if someone could possibly find that might solve your query.

Comment: @Mr.Llama I want a timeline to show what each thread was doing during the run time.